# ASP.NET MVC: Implementing an OpenID sign-in page ala NerdDinner v2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth, nerddinner

Consider the log in page on NerdDinner.com: http://www.nerddinner.com/Account/LogOn

Some nice features:

- jQuery effects on the OpenID choice
- popups for the other major providers

Is this revision of the NerdDinner AccountController and its View available for public download? How would you reinvent this implementation? Any code you can post would be fine.

Calling Jon Galloway!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of NerdDinner is available for [download from CodePlex](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/).

NerdDinner uses DotNetOpenAuth for its OpenID support, and the latest version of DotNetOpenAuth [available from the Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef) includes an ASP.NET MVC selector that does the same thing, although without a couple of the color and size styles picked to fit NerdDinner.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks, I didn't realize the new version of ND and its changesets were available for download. I'd only seen the packaged 1.0 source. Thanks again!