# How I Can code for Open Id in My Asp.net MVC Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to insert code for Open Id.
I am unable to find article based on this.
Please Help me With giving me a link of article?
Your articles help me very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566816/really-lost-with-openid-and-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [OpenIdPortableArea](http://openidportablearea.codeplex.com/).  It provides a controller and views that already contain the OpenId logic.  All you need to do is register the area with `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` and wire up a message handler, and you have access to the OpenId string that gets returned for the user.  The views are embedded, but can be overridden.  Check out the [documentation](http://openidportablearea.codeplex.com/documentation) for more comprehensive details.

If you're not familiar with portable areas, they are from [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.org).  There are some good [blog posts](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx) about how to get them going.  The OpenIdPortableArea uses [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net).

Otherwise, you can implement the logic yourself.  Here's a [great blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/899303.aspx) about how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563519/asp-net-mvc-implementing-an-openid-sign-in-page-ala-nerddinner-v2).

Comment: or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716/openid-authentication-in-asp-net

Comment: or indeed this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933884/request-for-tutorial-to-add-openid-support-to-nerddinner-asp-net-mvc-application